# Can I use Rails gem from another gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am developing a simple gem. as part of it, I want data-caching to which I need rails gem. I included the required statements in gemspec. But still, it is not loading Rails. I am getting below error

```
NameError:
   uninitialized constant FormattingHelper::Rails
```

Comment: If your gem requires rails, it is not a simple gem :)

Comment: Lol. But I am just trying to use Rails.cache

Comment: Yes, you will fail. Rails is a super-complicated beast. And you can't just "use it" (or parts of it) like that. Caching is a relatively simple task. Implement it without rails.

Comment: Any alternate gems, available, please?

Comment: memcache client, for example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Rails for caching, I used below class and fixed the problem

```
ActiveSupport::Cache
```